# IOS Submission No Certificate Found

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, code-signing-certificate

I was working on my app and had all the profiles created. The build was working perfectly, but my mac had crashed. I just got a new one, so I lost what was in keychain access. I downloaded the profiles and certificates from developer.apple.com.

When I open the project in Xcode, I can select the correct profile but it cannot find the certificates (no signing certificate "ios distribution" found).

Anyway to fix this? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new distribution certificate. It can be done in Xcode with:

1. Select Preferences… in the application menu
2. Select the Accounts tab
3. Select your AppleID
4. Select the team
5. Press the View Details… button
6. In the list of identities next to iOS Distribution, press the Create button

Alternatively it can be done by following a guide in the Apple developer member center.

The iOS distribution certificate is used for Ad Hoc distribition, Enterprise distribution and submitting the app to the App Store. It is not used when end users download the app from the App Store.